# How can I decrease the complexity of this function that calls back depending on data-type?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, ecmascript-6

I'm tweaking my authentication JavaScript module so I can handle my web app's authentication using one JavaScript class hook `.js-auth-ui`, while using data-type attributes to refer to the proper function.

After scanning the DOM for the js hooks, I'm running it through an init function as seen below, which in turn runs an exec function that calls back to the proper function.

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of writing the execAuthUi function without all the else if, which increase its "complexity" rating according to my linting rules.

```
const execAuthUi = function ( $element ) {
    const data = $element.data();

    if (data.type === "account-login-form") {
        authLoginEmail( $element, data );
    } else if (data.type === "account-logout") {
        authLogout( $element );
    } else if (data.type === "account-reset") {
        authReset( $element );
    } else if (data.type === "account-signup-form") {
        authSignup( $element );
    }
};

const initAuthUi = function ( ) {
    const $notLoaded = $_jsElements.not( ".is-initialized" );
    let $element = null;
    let i = $notLoaded.length;

    for ( i; i--; ) {
        $element = $_jsElements.eq( i );

        $element.addClass( "is-initialized" );

        execAuthUi( $element );
    }
};
```

Comment: Perhaps consider a switch/case statement?

Comment: Also personaly I would't consider this and overly complex function. Perhaps you just have an over zealous linter.

Comment: @Spaceman Thanks I agree, they are a little tough. However, the complexity is actually more extreme than this example so I wanted to come up with something a little more efficient. I'm also handling some other functions: `authLoginFacebook` and `authLoginTwitter`. The ideas in this thread helped greatly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an object mapping types to callbacks:

```
var callbackMap = {
    'account-login-form': authLoginEmail.bind(null, $element, data),
    'account-logout': authLogout.bind(null, $element),
    ...
};

callbackMap[data.type] && callbackMap[data.type]();
```

Comment: I never realized that, besides the `thisArg`, you could bind regular arguments with `bind()` as well. That's nice to come across.

Comment: Never seen bind before thats a nifty function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind for some ref if anyone else had the same discovery.

Comment: Great idea, this is exactly what I was looking for. I rolled with this idea and tweaked it a little. Love it!

Answer (score 0):

You could write it in a 'Switch' statement instead of using multiple elseifs.

I would do something like this

```
switch(data.type) {
  case "account-login-form": 
      authLoginEmail( $element, data );
      break;  
  case "account-logout": 
      authLogout( $element );
      break;
  case "account-reset":
      authReset( $element );
      break;
  case "account-signup-form":
      authSignup( $element );
      break;
}
```

You can also use a 'Default' case in case you have a method that does not meet any of these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a switch and move the checks out to be reusable.

```
const dataTypeAccountLoginForm = "account-login-form";
const dataTypeAccountLogout = "account-logout";
const dataTypeAccountReset = "account-reset";
const dataTypeAccountSignupForm = "account-signup-form";

const execAuthUi = function(ele){
  var data = ele.data();

  switch(data.type) {
    case dataTypeAccountLoginForm:
      authLoginEmail(ele, data);
      break;
    case dataTypeAccountLogout:
      authLogout(ele);
      break;
    case dataTypeAccountReset:
      authReset(ele);
      break;
    case dataTypeAccountSignupForm:
      authSignup(ele);
      break;
  }
}
```

Another option is to abstract the logic abit. Personaly I think doing it this way is a bit overkill.

```
var dataTypeAccountLoginForm = "account-login-form";
var dataTypeAccountLogout = "account-logout";
var dataTypeAccountReset = "account-reset";
var dataTypeAccountSignupForm = "account-signup-form";

var uiFunctions = [{ 
    key : dataTypeAccountLoginForm,
    func : authLoginEmail
  },
  { 
    key : dataTypeAccountLogout,
    func : authLogout
  },
  { 
    key : dataTypeAccountReset,
    func : authReset
  },
  { 
    key : dataTypeAccountSignupForm,
    func :  authSignup
}];

var execAuthUi = function(ele){
  var data = ele.data();

  for (var i = 0; i < uiFunctions.length; i++) {
    if (uiFunctions[i].key === data.type){
      uiFunctions[i].func(ele,data);
      return;
    }
  }
};
```

Or you could use a map function.

```
var dataTypeAccountLoginForm = "account-login-form";
var dataTypeAccountLogout = "account-logout";
var dataTypeAccountReset = "account-reset";
var dataTypeAccountSignupForm = "account-signup-form";

var uiFunctions = [
  { 
    key : dataTypeAccountLoginForm,
    func : authLoginEmail
  },
  { 
    key : dataTypeAccountLogout,
    func : authLogout
  },
  { 
    key : dataTypeAccountReset,
    func : authReset
  },
  { 
    key : dataTypeAccountSignupForm,
    func :  authSignup
  }
];

var execAuthUi = function(ele){
  var data = ele.data();

  uiFunctions.map(function(obj){
    if (obj.key === data.type)
      obj.func(ele,data);
  });

};
```